# SQL Connection String Generation

Tags: c#, sql

Is there any way to generate a connection string, or even read the connection string from a .txt file, what im I'm trying to achieve, is creating a button that will basically open the database, however I'm worried about the connection string since I will need to manipulate data on the database, this is the normal connectionstring string I have been using:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";
```

Summing it all up, how (or is it possible) to create a button that opens the database and generates the connection string? Assuming its a perfect world and the fields will be equal on all databases I use.

Comment: [MSDN: SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?  You can keep your connections strings in the code, in the config, or in an external resource like a text file.  "You're worried about the connection string" in what regard?  I feel like your question is not conveying the actual issue.

Comment: I'm sorry then, what im trying to do is open a database with a button, instead of adding it directly in the code, for example if i take the program on another computer where the database has a different name or a different path i can still use it, by opening it with a button, so basically a button that open the database, is it clear enough? i'm sorry if not explaining very well

Comment: So you want to go out and find the name of the database? This really doesn't seem secure nor safe.

Comment: It's only an academical exercise, im still learning, and this was on question that i have, and yes, imagining that the DB has a different name or path, the button will open it and generate the connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can pass the relevant fields as parameters (just use dictionary where the name is the key, and the value is... well, the value) and the button will call this method:

```
    public static string createConnectionString(Dictionary<string,string> parameters)
    {
        string res = string.Empty;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> entry in parameters)
        {
            res += entry.Key + "=" + entry.Value + ";";
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Here's an example how to use it:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("Data Source",".\wintouch");
        parameters.Add("Catalog","bbl");
        parameters.Add("ID","sa");
        parameters.Add("Password","Pa$$w0rd");
        string connectionString = createConnectionString(parameters);
```

Comment: Sorry for the maybe dumb question, but exactly what will this return?
Will it read a file or just ask me for the DB location?

Comment: this will let you create a string that is generated according to parameters you want. Where to get the parameters value is your choice.
Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: No, that does the trick i have been trying around and it works rather well, needs a little tweaking to suite my needs but this is the general idea i was looking for, thank you, very clear explanation as well.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could always use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

It will allow you to build strings such as:

`"server=My-PC\\SqlExpress;integrated security=SSPI;database=DataBaseName";`

`"server=My-PC\\SqlExpress;integrated security=false;UID=sa;PWD=APassword;database=DataBaseName";`